# eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0]) Shows me 0 balance though my syncing is still Running

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, etherscan, testnets, rinkeby

I am using **geth** on windows with `1.9.10` version.

I used `geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi="personal,eth,network,web3,net"` command for launch my  geth.

I am on the **Rinkeby testnet**, i already transfer 3 ether through **https://faucet.rinkeby.io/**, to my `0xf80a5cd42ff3a5d154399c83376ce99323e3ff69` address. And on **etherscan** it also shows me that transaction has been done. But when I tried to see in the **geth console** through `eth.getBalance(eth.account[0])` command, it showed me **0** balance. I tried too many times, but still it shows me **0** balance. When I try to `eth.syncing`, I am on the **3259367** current block and in my **etherscan** transaction block is **5846638**. So why it's shows me **0** balance?

Do I need to Syncing all nodes till **5846638** in my local computer ? or there are any thing that I am missing?

[image]

Comment: _"Do I need to Syncing all nodes till 5846638 in my local computer?"_ Yes, this is the issue. You'll need to wait until you've fully synced.

Answer (score 6):

When you sync your node, It fetches data previously written on the Blockchain. Hypothetically, let's say that:

- Node is currently syncing and had fetched the 100 first blocks
- the first time your account was transferred some tokens were at the block
  1000

In this scenario, at that precise point, if your node is still syncing, it won't have enough data to say that your account has some tokens. It will have to sync at least until the block 1000 to show that data. 
Hope this helps.

**[EDIT]** - Typos